# Why it can assign any function(one parameter) to type `(val:never) => void` in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

See the code below

```
interface Fn {
    (val: never): void
}

const fn1: Fn = () => {}
const fn2: Fn = (val: number) => {}
const fn3: Fn = (val: { canBeAnyThing: string }) => {}
```

There is no error, but I can not understand why. Here is an online demo on [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGImQbwLAChkHIAUAbnADYBcyIEJ0AlNSQPbAAmeAvnngiyADOYZDBABGaumQBeYg1kA+LD1z8hIsQCYpGOaQrUQAVwC2AI0ZKVfAcNEgAzLtnEyVLMgRwQAIQgAgiAAngAqABagAObUwlDRyFwKMsqYqkA)

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters + https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void in short, the compiler will stop you from calling `fn2(42)` for example, since that doesn't match the `Fn` interface. So, the parameter is irrelevant.

Comment: @VLAZ Thx for your comment, I did not know compiler would stop calling before. But I still not clear about that why compiler does not warn me when I assign a function to fn2

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer.

First of all, we need to figure out "covariance" and "contravariance"

After reading this article: [What are covariance and contravariance?](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance), we know that

> Contravariance in the argument type means A ≼ B implies (B → T) ≼ (A → T) (A and B flipped sides).

Cause `never` is the bottom type of TypeScript, which means

> never is a subtype of every other type

(get it from [When to use `never` and `unknown` in TypeScript](https://blog.logrocket.com/when-to-use-never-and-unknown-in-typescript-5e4d6c5799ad/#4f3d))

Combine the two rules, the code about the question above is totally OK.